# Why I cannot change slice to H512?

Tags: curl, types, rust

I am using `primitive_type` crate and make a post Http request using `rust-curl`.

https://docs.rs/primitive-types/0.3.0/primitive_types/struct.H512.html
https://docs.rs/curl/0.5.0/curl/easy/struct.Easy.html

```
pub fn hoge() {
    let param = "http://someurl.com/api/";
    let mut handle = Easy::new();
    let mut r = String::new(); 
    handle.url(&param.to_string()).unwrap();
    handle.post(true).unwrap();
    {
        let mut transfer = handle.transfer();
        transfer.write_function(|new_data| {
            r = String::from_utf8(Vec::from(new_data)).unwrap(); 
            Ok(stdout().write(new_data).unwrap())
        }).unwrap();
        transfer.perform().unwrap();
    }
    let b = H512::from_slice(&r.as_bytes());
}
```

and it becomes error :

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
left: `132`,
right: `64`', /Users/hogehoge/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/primitive-types-0.3.0/src/lib.rs:68:1
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
```

looks like param length does not match however is there any best way to return H512 type?

Comment: Is that the complete error message?

Comment: you should add a `println!("{:?}", r);` just before the `H512` creation and post the output. Chances are that you are actually getting `X="hash-in-hexadecimal"` or something like that.

Comment: Just `println!("{:?}", r)" before the `H512` it shows hex string `"0xce4b857efc938874ff4af01258f01e35fd892f6d16e48f9eff3580960db58a890795d69bba43cffbda9df70f30fc1bb792ba2aad6aa4bdd236714fc04b2b8fa8\""`

Comment: `H512` is a newtype wrapper for a `[u8; 64]`, which presumably is where the 64 is coming from in that assertion. It seems like `from_slice` is asserting that the length of the slice is exactly 64, but your slice is too big.

Comment: You have a string, including a leading `0x` and trailing `\"`. That's an extra 4 characters, so the "actual" data is 128 characters long. This is just 64 bytes in hex. So you need to convert it to bytes before `H512::from_slice` can handle it.

Comment: Or just avoid converting your raw data to a UTF8 string in the first place? Use a `Vec<u8>` instead of a `String` would be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just worked out this way :

```
pub fn hoge() -> std::io::Result<(H512)> {
    let param = "http://someurl.com/api/";
    let mut handle = Easy::new();
    let mut r = String::new();
    handle.url(&param.to_string()).unwrap();
    handle.post(true).unwrap();
    {
        let mut transfer = handle.transfer();
        transfer.write_function(|new_data| {
            r = String::from_utf8(Vec::from(new_data)).unwrap();
            Ok(new_data.len())
        }).unwrap();
        transfer.perform().unwrap();
    }
    let r = r.replace("\"","").replacen("0x", "", 1);
    let result = H512::from_slice(&hex::decode(&r).expect("decode failed"));
    Ok(result)
}
```

is there any better ways?